# Making us better programmers "In depth"

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Reading through [this amazing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/939944) to "Logging best practices" I am struck (again) by the value of this kind of long-form answer. Value to me, as a programmer. This is the kind of big picture view you'd need to read a thousand question/answers to glean.

The normal shrug-off of "this would make a good blog post" is unacceptable, in my eyes. Especially since the new documentation beta started (because the trite answer to the documentation problem would also be "it's the problem of the API/library/language author").

So what I would like to see is some way to encourage this kind of big-picture, know-it-all-or-near-enough-in-a-few-minutes, *In Depth* overview of subjects inside (or alongside) the documentation functionality.

Currently, the whole structure and editing experience of Documentation doesn't really favour long-form anything. It's tailored to snappy single-issue Examples. Personally, I think there would arguably be *more* added value in the kind of long-form stuff (as it's got less of a home on SO).

Discuss.

Comment: You say *Discuss* but this is tagged as a feature request.  Do you have a suggestion for how to accomplish this or do you want to talk about how this could be accomplished?

Comment: Posts like that are already naturally encouraged on Stack Overflow: over their lifetimes, they are going to accumulate _lots_ of recognition, maybe more so than an equivalent blog post.

Their rarity is also completely natural: writing a long coherent piece of _anything_ requires a good deal of effort.

Answer (score 2):

> The normal shrug-off of "this would make a good blog post" is unacceptable

Why is it unacceptable?  If someone wants to post content like this is *very* easy for them to do so.  There are *lots* of places on the internet that are built *specifically* to host this type of content.

SO just isn't one of those places.  It's not build to host that type of content, and *it doesn't need to be* as there are so many other places where it *is* possible and it *is* easy.

SO can't be everything to everyone; as a site it has worked to focus the scope of what it covers so that it can cover it well, and have a site that is extremely well suited to the content that it does want to cover.  It has chosen to make that type of content out of its scope, so that it can better serve other types of content.

Comment: Everything you say here also applies to documenting APIs as far as I'm concerned.